# Why Firebase Messaging is not working after reinstalling my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had just implemented correctly Firebase, it worked perfectly until I uninstalled the app and run again from Xcode. From that point it doesn't receive any Firebase notification, neither background or foreground. How can it be possible? All the certificates seem to be ok. Here is my AppDelegate.m:

```
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    [FIRApp configure];

    // Managing notifications:

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
             if(!error){
                 [self registerForNotification];
             }
         }];

    } else {
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]){

            // iOS 8 Notifications:

            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

            [self registerForNotification];

        } else {

            // iOS < 8 Notifications

            [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{    
    NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error.description);
}


// To receive notifications for iOS 9 and below.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // Print message ID.
  NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)registerForNotification {
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // iOs 8 or greater:

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

        UIMutableUserNotificationAction *open;
        open = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [open setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
        [open setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil)];
        [open setIdentifier:NotificationActionOpenView];
        [open setDestructive:NO];
        [open setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

        UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
        actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
        [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryOpenView];
        [actionCategory setActions:@[open] 
                        forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
        UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
        settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                     categories:categories];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)]) { 
        // iOs 7 or lesser:

        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sending a notification via the console or from your own App Server?

Comment: Through the Firebase console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case could benefit someone, the missing part was this:

```
      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    // for development 
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];

    // for production 
   //     [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, no errors. It seems like it's a synchronization problem with Google's servers or something. It happened to me and it starts to work after 1 hour of having installed the app.

Just wait :)